# Regex for capturing password requirements

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out how to format a regex in python that would capture the following password requirements:
a.  At least one of the following special characters (#, %, @, &)
b.  At least one number
c.  At least one upper case alphabet
d.  At least 6 characters

Right now, I have come up with this, which has worked for some passwords and not others:

[A-Za-z0-9@#%&]{6,}

I'm having trouble with differentiating between mandatory elements (the requirements) and things that would be optional, like having a lowercase letter. Is there a way to format these requirements without using lookaheads/look behinds? I've seen examples doing password requirement regex with those but I'm wondering how I could do it without that.

Comment: Don't have annoying password requirements that break password manager generation and ban perfectly legitimate passwords. https://www.totalhipaa.com/password-guidelines-updated-by-nist/

Comment: If this is even possible it would need a complicated pattern with many alternatives (`|`) at least one alternative for each possible order of the required characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a series of lookaheads to make these checks, because that's what lookaheads are, zero-width conditionals that don't consume characters:

```
(?=.*[#%@&])(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PA1O05/3/)